# How to include output from etable() of fixest package as latex regression table into markdown as html output?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, xtable, fixest

I would like to include the regression output from `etable(feols(fml = formula, data = data, cluster = ~cluster))` as latex regression table into an rmarkdown creating an html output.

My regression function at the moment is this one:

```
regression <- function(analysis_data,formula) {
  print(xtable(etable(feols(fml = formula,
               data = analysis_data  
               , cluster = ~ cluster_var)
         , 
         keep = c("var1", "var2")), type = "html", include.rownames = F))
}
```

My rmarkdown chunk header for the specific chunk that should include the latex table into the html document is the following:

```
{r chunk1, eval = T, echo = F, warning=FALSE, out.width= "150%", message = F, results='asis'}
```

And my general header of the rmarkdown document is:

```
---
title: "Title"
#author: "My name"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: inline

---

<style>
div.hidecode + pre {display: none}
</style>
<script>
doclick=function(e){
e.nextSibling.nextSibling.style.display="block";
}
</script>
```

I also tried varying my regression function to (using the same chunk header where `results = 'asis'`) without success:

```
regression <- function(analysis_data,formula) {
  etable(feols(fml = formula,
               data = analysis_data  
               , cluster = ~ cluster_var)
         , 
         keep = c("var1", "var2"), tex = T)
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated!